# WaitForMultipleObjects and several SetEvent()'s

Tags: visual-c++, waitformultipleobjects

I process some event, signaled by WFMO, and at this time it's signaled more N times. Would WFMO return once or N times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once. An event is basically like a Boolean variable; `SetEvent` is pretty much the same as `event =  true;` -- setting it to true if it's already true has no effect.

If you want something that keeps count, consider using a semaphore instead of an event.